# How to create dynamic content with get_post_meta?

Tags: plugin-development

If i create php dynamic website i use the code something like this

```
<input type="text" name="fname">
$name = $_POST['fname'];
echo $name;
```

In WordPress i have created a plugin. Inside is a metabox with one input text field “name”.

I try to create dynamic content with variables so i can “echo” them anywhere in front pages. More specific in each “directory” post pages it must display dynamically at the page 1 the name “John” and the second page the name “Jane”.

Here is my code:

```
$args = array(
                'post_type' => array( 'directory' ),
                'order'     => 'ASC',
            );

            // The Query
            $query = new WP_Query( $args );

            // The Loop
          if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                    $query->the_post();
                }
            } else {
                 no posts found
            }

    $name = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'name', true );
        
    if( !empty( $name )  ) {
        echo $name;
    }
    else {
        echo "Empty meta";
    }
```

Can anyone show me an example on wordpress code about how to create dynamic content with get_post_meta or show me what i am doing wrong ?

**Update for question of Antti Koskinen 10-Sep-2021**

```
function prfx_custom_meta() {
    add_meta_box( 'prfx_meta',
                 __( 'Meta Box Title', 'prfx-textdomain' ),
                  'prfx_meta_callback',
                  'directory'
                );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'prfx_custom_meta' );

/**
 * Outputs the content of the meta box
 */
function prfx_meta_callback( $post ) {
    wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'prfx_nonce' );
    $prfx_stored_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID );
    ?>
 
    <p>
        <label for="name" class="prfx-row-title"><?php _e( 'Name', 'prfx-textdomain' )?></label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php if ( isset ( $prfx_stored_meta['name'] ) ) echo $prfx_stored_meta['name'][0]; ?>" />
    </p>

    
    <?php
}

function prfx_meta_save( $post_id ) {
 
    // Checks save status
    $is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id );
    $is_revision = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id );
    $is_valid_nonce = ( isset( $_POST[ 'prfx_nonce' ] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ 'prfx_nonce' ], basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) ? 'true' : 'false';
 
    // Exits script depending on save status
    if ( $is_autosave || $is_revision || !$is_valid_nonce ) {
        return;
    }
 
    // Checks for input and sanitizes/saves if needed
    if( isset( $_POST[ 'name' ] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'name' ] ) );
    }
    
         
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'prfx_meta_save' );
```

For showing in frontend i use:

```
$args = array(
                'post_type' => array( 'directory' ),
                'order'     => 'ASC',
            );

            // The Query
            $query = new WP_Query( $args );

            // The Loop
          if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                    $query->the_post();
                }
            } else {
                 no posts found
            }

    $name = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'name', true );

    if( !empty( $name )  ) {
        echo $name;
    }
    else {
        echo "Empty meta";
    }
```

Comment: Could you share your metabox code so the community can see how it is done and how the custom inputs are saved, please? And if the post meta is supposed to be shown for the `directory` posts you're looping, then move the post meta fetching inside the `while` loop.

Comment: Hi Antti Koskinen, I am very sorry for delay to answer your question. I have update the code.